# search for specific html tags if contain specific words

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following  regex code

> `/<a href="(.*)".*>(?:Refund|Refound|Refunds|return|returns)<\/a>/Ui`

to match if there are refund or return between these tags, but it won't match any thing

the html data I'm searching in

```
 <li class="site-footer__linklist-item">
                 <a href="/pages/shipping-return-policy">Shipping Return Policy</a>
               </li>
```

I'm using https://regexr.com/   to test the code

How can I make it check if it contain one of  these words (?:Refund|Refound|Refunds|return|returns)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DOMDocument` class to get the `nodeValue` of `a` tag followed by `preg_match`.

```
$str = '<li class="site-footer__linklist-item"><a href="/pages/shipping-return-policy">Shipping Return Policy</a></li>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $a){
    $val = $a->nodeValue;
    if(preg_match("/Refund(s)?|Refound|return(s)?/i", $val)) {
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

However if you still want to do it regex way, here it is:

```
<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>.*?(Refunds?|Refound|returns?).*?<\/a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can I user regex only to achieve that ?

Comment: @areviewsapp Yes you can but it is always a good idea to parse html/xml using `DOMDocument`.

Comment: @areviewsapp Here is your regex: `<a.*?href=".*?(Refunds?|Refound|returns?)`

Comment: If you notice I'm trying to capture what in href and search in what between the tags only  not inside it   "Shipping Return Policy"

Comment: @areviewsapp I did not notice that, here is your regex: `<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>.*?(Refunds?|Refound|returns?).*?<\/a>`